# Microsoft SQL Server Stored Procedure with a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

After three days of intensive Googling, trying, failing, bargaining and getting angry. I have accepted my fate and decided to ask you. I will try to be as clear as possible here.
.

I am trying to select a single field from the database (via a SP) here are some of the things I have tried:

**Subquerywise:**

```
(
    SELECT dbo.T_MemoDetail.Info
    FROM dbo.T_MemoDetail
    INNER JOIN dbo.T_DossierDetail AS T_DossierDetail
            ON T_DossierDetail.MemoGrpId = dbo.T_MemoDetail.MemoGrpId
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_DossierMain AS T_DossierMain
            ON T_DossierDetail.DossierCode = T_DossierMain.DossierCode
    WHERE T_DossierDetail.MemoGrpId = dbo.T_MemoDetail.MemoGrpId AND
    T_DossierDetail.DossierCode = T_DossierMain.DossierCode AND
    T_DossierMain.OrdNr = 'BVR13-0710'
),
```

^Returns 2 Strings

```
SELECT 
    /*Selects a lot more, but i do not want to paste the whole SP here*/
    T_MemoDetail.Info **Note that this isn't a subquery**
    /*Selecting more data beneath here*/
FROM dbo.T_DossierMain
    INNER JOIN dbo.T_DossierDetail AS t10 
        ON t10.DossierCode = t1.DossierCode
    INNER JOIN dbo.T_MemoDetail AS T_MemoDetail
        ON T_MemoDetail.MemoGrpId = t10.MemoGrpId AND
        t10.DossierCode = t1.DossierCode
```

also tried using a Temporary table with both ways
`CREATE TABLE #Temp ....... INSERT INTO SELECT`
and
`SELECT ...... INTO #Temp`

**ONLY** links between the damn tables

```
T_DossierDetail.MemoGrpId = dbo.T_MemoDetail.MemoGrpId AND  
T_DossierDetail.DossierCode = T_DossierMain.DossierCode AND  
T_DossierMain.OrdNr BETWEEN @OrdFrom AND @OrdTo (filled with textboxes in FastReport)
```

**NOTE**
The only value in the table `T_DossierDetail` that is Distinct is the combination of DetailCode and DetailSubCode

If anyone can help me out with this one, I would be so greatfull

**EDIT 1.1**

Hope this helps...

(Usable) values for T_DossierDetail:

```
MemoGrpId,DossierCode,DetailCode,DetailSubCode  
5468, 015402,010,000  
5469, 015402,020,000
```

(Usable) values for T_DossierMain:

```
OrdNr,T_DossierMain.DossierCode  
BVR13-0710, 015402
```

(Usable) values for T_DossierMain:

```
T_MemoDetail.MemoGrpId, T_MemoDetail.Info  
5468, [CompanyName] Logo  
5469, [CompanyName] Logo
```

All values are returned as strings, not int, double, float or anything STRINGS ONLY (for some reason), FYI: I'm just an intern

[image: The "Involves" tables]

Comment: You have 2 identicals value? It's probably a problem with your link, are you sure you are correctly joining all the field from primary keys?

Comment: Maybe you have 2 rows in DossierDetail for that folder with no 'BVR13-0710'.

Comment: @MatheseF they are not the primary keys but they are the only way of linking from one table to another (or is that a primary key?) Also the string values that are to be returned are identical but I'll see if I can't edit it clearer BRB

Comment: @SQLhint.com It basically selects a lot of data from dossiermain where ordnr = 'BVR13-0710' then uses its return values (a single row with a lot of colomns) to select and get the rest

Comment: Can you show us, or send me the structure for the tables involes plz, i send as answer a case where you will duplicate the values :)

Comment: @MatheseF i added a basic, quickley made, model of the usable tables and relevant fields

Comment: Yes you have multiple result and it's logic even if it's not what you want :) You have T_DossierMain, you link to DossierDetail and you find 2 rows. From there you join the last and you keep your 2 rows. If you only want one, you should use a top 1, min/max, perhaps a distinct or a more complex query (for example select the first detail code)

Comment: @MatheseF I know i get 2 rows (it means it works), but in the bloody report it shows rows 1 and 2 twice and that is what I've been trying to repair/fix/work around

Comment: @MatheseF it returns DetailCode/DetailSubcode combo twice (i.e. 010/000 first row | 020/000 second row | 010/000 first row AGAIN | 020/000 second row AGAIN) I hope this clears it up. Been fiddling around a bit, but it just refuses to cooperate (I'm starting to lose hope...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of key not correctly used :

```
declare @table1 table (key1 int, key2 int, value1 int)
declare @table2 table (key1 int, key2 int, key3 int, value2 int)

insert into @table1 values (1,1,1)
insert into @table1 values (1,2,2)

insert into @table2 values (1,1,1,1)

select t2.value2 
from @table1 t1
inner join @table2 t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key1
where t2.key3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 rows because you have a dossier with 2 details rows. That's the way a join works: it takes all the rows from left table (=dossier details, 2 rows) and match them with the right table (=main dossier, 1 row).

You have too add a new condition, to filter condition your data in a way to keep only one row from dossier detail:

```
    SELECT
        MD.Info
    FROM dbo.T_MemoDetail MD
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_DossierDetail DD ON DD.MemoGrpId = MD.MemoGrpId
        INNER JOIN dbo.T_DossierMain DM ON DD.DossierCode = DM.DossierCode
    WHERE 
        DM.OrdNr = 'BVR13-0710'
```

P.S. You put twice some JOIN conditions => it is not necessary...

Comment: I know that, but i do not see any way to do that using the `DetailCode` and `DetailSubCode` from `T_DossierDetail`

Comment: @CasNouwens: I don't understand your question. At the moment, you're asking for 2 rows and you get 2 rows. Tell us in words what do you want to achieve...

Comment: in the report itself, when i look at the print preview, it shows the 2 lines (010 and 020) twice, so 4 lines while there should be 2 and the inner join of DossierDetail makes that happen.

Comment: I want it to return DISTINCT values, only way i see how to do that, is by combining the DetailCode and DetailSubCode and forcing it take them distinct so that the 2 lines won't be displayed twice

Comment: @CasNouwens: I've update the SQL. When you join those 3 tables you will have x rows where x = rowsInDM x rowsInDD x rowsInMD.

Comment: did you mean to use this as a subquery, or should i implement it into the main query that selects about 25 fields?

Comment: and if i implement it as a subquery it does work, FastReport doesn't load the dataset (throwing this error "SQL Error Code: 512 Subquery returned more than 1 value This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression").... I have encountered this before